# Remove span elements with the same Ids and only let one remain

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an HTML string. i want to select all span elements and remove spans with the same IDs and only let one of them remain in the string. The text between the span elements should not be deleted.

The spans with the same IDs are all after each other.
The remained one should wrap all the removed ones text.

e.g:

Input:

```html
<p>
  Hi,<span id="1">this is just a simple text and we</span>
  <span id="1">want to save me because i had a lot of</span>
  <span id="1">pressure on and i want to live a better life. </span>
  I researched a lot about it but i could't find anything helpful
  <span id="2">just another rant. </span>
</p>
```

Output:

```html
<p>
  Hi, 
  <span id="1">
      this is just a simple text and we want to save me because i had a lot of 
      pressure on and i want to live a better life 
  </span>
  I researched a lot about it but i could't find anything helpful
  <span id="2">just another rant. </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A short solution**

A short solution would be to select all the spans with an id and use Array.reduce() to concat the content of spans with the same id.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("span[id]")].reduce((last,span) => {

  if (span.id === last.id) {
    last.innerHTML += ' \n' + span.innerHTML;
    span.remove();
    return last;
  }
  return span;

}, {});
```

**Snippet**

```js
before.value = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML;

[...document.querySelectorAll("span[id]")].reduce((last,span) => {

  if (span.id === last.id) {
    last.innerHTML += ' \n' + span.innerHTML;
    span.remove();
    return last;
  }
  return span;

}, {});


after.value = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7rem;
  font-size: 10px;
}
p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Hi,<span id="1">this is just a simple and we</span>
  <span id="1">want to save me for becuase i had a lot of</span>
  <span id="1">presure on and i want to live a betteer life. </span>
  I researched a lot about it but i could't find anything helpful
  <span id="2">just another rant. </span>
  <span id="3">Hello World</span>
  <span id="3">Duplicate World</span>
  <span>A span without an ID</span>
</p>

Before:
<textarea id="before"></textarea>

After:
<textarea id="after"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly what you want to achieve.

Since you can't have more than one element with the same id.
In Example 2 I replaced ID with a class.

The algorithm takes all the span elements in the code.
It then scrolls through all the elements of the collected sheet and takes their contents.
Deletes all elements of a given class except the first! In the first element, put the collected information.

I hope I've been helpful

**Example with ID:**
In this example I use jQuery

```js
let list = [...$('span')];

let tempText = '';

list.forEach((el, i) => {

    let currElID = el.getAttribute('id');

    let nextElID = null;

    if (list[i + 1]) {
        nextElID = list[i + 1].getAttribute('id');
    } else {
        nextElID = null;
    };


    tempText += el.innerText;


    if (currElID !== nextElID) {

        let listByClass = [...$(`[id=${currElID}]`)];

        if (listByClass.length > 0) {
            listByClass.forEach((element, index) => {
                if (index > 0) {
                    element.remove();
                }
            });
        };

        listByClass[0].innerText = tempText;

        tempText = '';
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
    Hi,
    <span id="1">this is just a simple and we</span>
    <span id="1">want to save me for becuase i had a lot of</span>
    <span id="1">presure on and i want to live a betteer life. </span>
    I researched a lot about it but i could't find anything helpful
    <span id="2">just another rant. </span>
</p>
```

**Example with CLASS:**

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('span');

let tempText = '';

list.forEach((el, i) => {

    let currElClass = el.getAttribute('class');

    let nextElClass = null;

    if (list[i + 1]) {
        nextElClass = list[i + 1].getAttribute('class');
    } else {
        nextElClass = null;
    };

    
    tempText += el.innerText;


    if (currElClass !== nextElClass) {

        let listByClass = [...document.getElementsByClassName(currElClass)];

        if (listByClass.length > 0) {
            listByClass.forEach((element, index) => {
                if (index > 0) {
                    element.remove();
                }
            });
        };

        listByClass[0].innerText = tempText;

        tempText = '';
    };

});
```

```html
<p>
    Hi,
    <span class="1">this is just a simple and we</span>
    <span class="1">want to save me for becuase i had a lot of</span>
    <span class="1">presure on and i want to live a betteer life. </span>
    I researched a lot about it but i could't find anything helpful
    <span class="2">just another rant. </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

While `id` is unique, you can still achieve your result without switching to using `class` instead. (if you *can* switch to using class, do.)

The following code finds the first instance of your duplicate id, copies the text content then deletes the element. this repeats until there are no more. A new element is then added and populated with the text content stored earlier.

```js
let e = []
while (i = document.getElementById("one")) {
  e.push(i.textContent);
  i.parentNode.removeChild(i)
}
let x = document.createElement("div")
x.setAttribute("id", "one")

x.innerHTML = e.join("<br>")

document.body.appendChild(x)
```

```html
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="one">Two</div>
<div id="one">Three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find all *spans* with *id* set:

```js
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("span[id]");
```

For each span:

```js
for (let span of spans)
```

If next element of a given *span* is another *span* with the same *id*:

```js
(nextElement && nextElement.nodeName === "SPAN" && span.id === nextElement.id)
```

then move all *nodes* between the *spans* into the first *span*:

```js
let nextNode = span.nextSibling;
while(nextNode !== nextElement) {
  span.append(nextNode);
  nextNode = span.nextSibling;
}
```

as well as all the *nodes* from the second *span*:

```js
span.append(...nextElement.childNodes);
```

remove the second *span*:

```js
nextElement.remove();
```

and then continue the same procedure for the new sibling:

```js
nextElement = span.nextElementSibling;
```

Since there's no point to process already removed *spans* with duplicate *ids*, skip them:

```js
if (!span.parentNode) {
  continue;
}
```

Finally, the *spans NodeList* should be released to avoid memory leaks:

```js
spans = null;
```

Normally all DOM manipulations should be batched (moved to the very end of the code and done all at once) for performance reasons but this would complicate the code a bit so I didn't include that in the snippet below to make the code easier to follow.

```js
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("span[id]");
for (let span of spans) {
  if (!span.parentNode) {
    continue;
  }
  let nextElement = span.nextElementSibling;
  while (nextElement && nextElement.nodeName === "SPAN" && span.id === nextElement.id) {
    let nextNode = span.nextSibling;
    while (nextNode !== nextElement) {
      span.append(nextNode);
      nextNode = span.nextSibling;
    }
    span.append(...nextElement.childNodes);
    nextElement.remove();
    nextElement = span.nextElementSibling;
  }
}
spans = null;
```

```html
<p>
  Hi,<span id="1">this is just a simple and we</span>
  <span id="1">want to save me for becuase i had a lot of</span>
  <span id="1">presure on and i want to live a betteer life. </span> I researched a lot about it but i could't find anything helpful
  <span id="2">just another rant. </span>
</p>
```